# Jquery nested elements created dynamically have css styles and js events broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I'm need to create the following form structure:

```
<div class="lg-pnl" id="logP">
  <form id="form">
    <div class="fields" id="fields1">

      <div class="txt">
       <label for="user" class="ent-u"></label>
       <input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="user"/>
     </div>

     <div class="txt">
       <label for="pw" class="ent-l"></label> 
       <input id="pw" type="password" name="password" class="validate[required] pw-input" placeholder="pwd"/> 
     </div>

     <div class="btn"> 
        <input type="submit" value="GO" id="subGO"/>
     </div>   
   </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And for archieve this I'm using the very very very ugly code bellow:

```
$("#logP").append('<form id="form">');
$("#logP form").append('<div class="fields"></div>');
$("#logP form .fields").append('<div class="txt"></div>');
$("#logP form .fields .txt").append('<label for="user" class="ent-u"/>');
$("#logP form .fields .txt").append('<input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="user"/>');
$("#logP form .fields .txt").append('<label for="pw" class="ent-l"/>');
$("#logP form .fields .txt").append('<input id="pw" type="password" name="password" class="validate[required] pw-input" placeholder="pwd"/>');
$("#logP form .fields").append('<div class="btn"></div>');
$("#logP form .fields .buttons").append('<input type="submit" value="GO" id="subGO"/>');
```

I really need to preserve this DOM tree because the CSS style works on it.

[image]

But the styles isn't work properly neither the js events bind with form and input elements,
I have lost all behaviour for these functions, for example the piece of code bellow doesn't work anymore.

```
div.lg-pnl div.txt input[type="text"],
div.lg-pnl div.txt input[type="password"]

$('.subGO').click(function() {
       $('#form').validation('validate');
}); 

 $(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
       this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

So I'm trying to find out some better way to create this entire form and its own elements 
dynamically without losing the styles and the id/class references in the javascript already 
defined.

I'll  really appreciate your suggestions

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
 $(document).on('click', '.subGO',function() {
     $('#form').validation('validate');
 });
```

Replace `document` with nearest static container. i.e. `"#logP"`

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: Thank you man so much. Your suggestion sounds appropriate but I'll still dealing with style errors.  I want to find a more suitable and programmatically strategy to create elements on the fly.